# How to know dock size?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, dock

In my app, I need to know what the dock size is at the moment my app is running (I don't want to modify the dock, only know its size).
Here is what I found until now :

- no direct way to interact with dock
- using com.apple.dock.plist, I can know the tilesize and the number of persistent apps and persistent others so I "could" compute dock size but only for persistent elements. What I want is the dock size at the moment I ask it and there can be other launched apps which are not listed in persistent apps in the plist so my computed size is wrong.

Has anyone ever faced the same issue ? Do I have to loop through each running app in order to guess if it has an item in the dock ? Is there an other easier way to get the dock size ?

All ideas are very welcome. Thanks in advance for your answers, hints...

Comment: Ok, I can answer this, but I don't know what you mean by "size".  Do you want the "count" of total items, or the pixel dimensions?

Comment: I would be interested in the icon number and pixel dimensions

Answer (score 4):

Besides [NSDockTile](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSDockTile_Class/Reference/Reference.html) also have a look at [NSScreen](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScreen_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScreen/visibleFrame) to compute the size of the dock.

Comment: Thanks for the hint Bakotaco.